# Which status code should be sent to client when accessToken has expired and the client needs to send refresh token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, token, http-status-codes

I am building an API which uses jwt for authentication. I use a middleware to decode the token and set the req.user before every route.

```
app.use(async (req, res, next)=>{
    const token = req.headers.accessToken;
    if(!token){
        req.user = undefined;
        next()
    }
    try{
        const user = await jwt.verify(token, SECRET)
        req.user = user
        next()
    }catch(err){ // token present but invalid
        res.status(which status to use?).json(err)
    }   
})
```

If the token is present but is invalid/expired, I want to ask the client to send the refresh token. Which status code should I use. I could use a `403` which means unauthorized, but if the token has just expired, the user is authorized but only needs a new token.I dont want the client to confuse this `403` status with the one sent when the user is actually not authorized to access a resource.

Since I was not able to find the answer on google, I suspect that this is not the way to handle  tokens. Is there a better way?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Ok thank you. Is this the standard way to validate tokens?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**401 - Unauthorized** : 401 - is the status code used when the client request has not been completed because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the requested resource.

Have a look at this [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) once :